Patterns of coefficient and constant in Simultaneous equations with arithmetic sequence
My requirement for this scenario is that simultaneous equations must have equations where the coefficient and constant needs to follow an arithmetic sequence.
E.g.
$2\times2$ system
$ax+(a+b)y=(a+2b)$
$sx+(s+t)y=(s+2t)$
And
$3\times3$ system
$ax+(a+b)y+(a+2b)z= (a+3b)$
$sx+(s+t)y+(s+2t)z= (s+3t)$
$mx+(m+n)y+(m+2n)z= (m+3n)$
So I need to find out the conditions and the patterns of the coefficient or constant that will give unique, infinite or no solution when solving these simultaneous equations from arithmetic sequence.
For $2\times 2$ system, I have found out that it can yield unique solutions of $x=-1, y=2$ when the determinant equals not zero and the slopes of both equations aren't proportional.
Eg.
$2x+5y=8$
$x+4=7$
But there will be infinite solutions when the determinant is zero with slopes that are proportional.
E.g.
$x+2y=3$
$2x+4y=6$
But I haven't found cases where there are no solutions. Am I right thinking it cant happen because no solution requires the same slope but diff constant(y int) and due to the arithmetic sequence requirement it can't happen?
For $3\times 3$ systems, the only solutions I get is infinite solutions. If the equations in this system all don't have slopes that proportional with each other it will be infinite as when graphed on a 3d Cartesian plane, they all meet along the same line. Ig another way to get infinite solutions is when all the equations in the system are proportional with each other which results into them being a single plane?
But I can't find cases where there will be no solutions or unique solutions whilst still following the arithmetic sequence requirement. I thought with no solutions that when graphed it means there so be a pair or all that are parallel but how do you do that whilst making the equation follow arithmetic sequence. And for unique solutions I have no idea about it.
So Is it possible or not to have unique or no solutions in this scenario for $3\times 3$ system and no solutions for $2\times 2$ system? I would like to know. If it is, please give an example but if it is not then a reasoning why would be great. Also what patterns of the coefficient and constant terms and combinations (multiple) which affect the solutions

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Are you familiar with vector/matrix formulations ,

No, your $3 \times 3$ system will never have $0$ or a unique solution.
Here is why. This system is equivalent with vector notations, to :
$$(x+y+z)\pmatrix{a\\s\\m}+(1+2)\pmatrix{b\\t\\m}=\pmatrix{a\\s\\m}+3\pmatrix{b\\t\\m}$$
Otherwise said :
$$(x+y+z)\underbrace{\pmatrix{a\\s\\m}}_V=\pmatrix{a\\s\\m}\tag{1}$$
Therefore, (1) can be splitted into 2 cases :

either $V \ne 0$ (i.e., not all its entries are $O$) : in this case the solution set is the infinite set of $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z=1$ (a plane).

otherwise any $(x,y,z)$ is a solution.



In the $2\times 2$ case, the solution will always be $x=-1,y=2$ if the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ and the constant term are in arithmetic progression.
It is actually quite easy to see this by substitution:
Take one equation of the form $ax+(a+d)y=a+2d$
Substituting $x=-1,y=2$ the left hand side becomes $-a+2a+2d$ which simplifies to $a+2d$ which is the right hand side.
In terms of no solutions, this would require a set of parallel but non-coincident lines. However, since every line of the form $ax+(a+d)y=a+2d$ will pass through the point $(-1,2)$ this is not possible.
There is a phrase (not in common usage anymore) referring to such systems as a pencil of lines which may be of some interest for further research.
The $3\times 3$ case will be two planes meeting in a line, and the specifics of this have already been given in another (excellent) answer, so I will not reproduce them here.
